# Banished Babies

Tags: banished

On banished, the game about creating a village and surviving the seasons, I have encountered a problem with a massive lack of babies. Is there any easy way of stopping this other than destroying the condom factory?

Answer (score 10):

Villagers can only get children when they don't live with their parents anymore. So you need to make sure that you have enough unoccupied houses for your young adults to move into.

Answer (score 2):

Babies are born in banished when there is a excess of houses for adults to move into. When villagers move out of their parents' homes and into their own homes, they start to have kids.

If you want to increase your population, build more houses.

If you want to keep the population where it is, do not build more houses.